# Tracking debugging constants with git

Tags: git

I am an enthusiastic git user and I have a code that relies on a set of debugging constants to turn on or off logging, pre-filled forms and other behaviors that doesn't belong in a production build.

The question is really language-agnostic, but in java you can think as something like this:

```
public static final DEBUG_LOGS = true;
public static final DEBUG_SKIP_FORM = true;
...
```

The debugging switches can be isolated into a separate file (e.g. a class with static members only, a C header file,...) but the more I develop, and the more I face the following problem:

*Should I find a way to `.gitignore` the file (perhaps keeping always the production ready version), keep it with all the (frequent) changes and clutter the repository, or should I skip it manually skipping when staging? Are there other solutions?*

What's the *correct* way (pragmatically speaking), of dealing with this situation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is a "build configuration file". If it is in the repo at all, it should exist only as a template. The build does not refer to the template. Rather, some documentation says that you must locally copy `build_config_template.whatever` to `build_config.whatever` (and please do not add the latter to the repository).

The template can have the preferred settings for doing a production build so that people who want to do the most common build type don't have to change it at all, or have to do very little to it.

If you follow open source projects, you probably  may have seen that many use a script called `./configure` which generates build configuration files (for instance for C programs) such as `config.make`, `config.h` and others. Even entire `Makefile`-s are generated: a `Makefile.in` template is preprocessed with the substitution of some material resulting in `Makefile`, and in some cass the `Makefile.in` template is itself generated from `Makefile.am`. (As you can see, people have come up with very elaborate solutions to build configuration problems.)

If you do not run this configure script, the software can't build because pieces of the program and its build system are missing. The generated pieces like `config.make` and `config.h` are not checked in or packaged in source distributions. (Though certain generated pieces, like the configure script itself, are packaged and sometimes end up checked into repos. For every rule there are justified exceptions.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I confess I felt stupid when you mentioned the `autotools` since I created many `Makefile`s, and some `configure.ac` myself (so I sort of know the theory), but for some reason I wasn't able to make a parallel with the scenarios I'm recently in (lot of IDEs and awkward build systems in general... :( ). Very good answer, btw: in order to be fair, I'll wait a while to see if someone else will come up with something interesting (if not better), otherwise I'll mark your answer as the correct solution.